# Does Presto have the equivalent of Hive's SET command

Tags: presto

It's very convenient to be able to set script variables.  For example,

SET start_date = 20151201;

SELECT * FROM some_table where date = {$hiveconf:start_date};

Does Presto have this capability?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not yet.
Presto only have set session command for setting some presto properties during current session.
For example 
SET SESSION distributed_join=true;

But presto can not set a variable and use it in following sql like hive does.

Comment: But this seems not difficult, I can try to add this when I have time.

Comment: Did you end up having time to add this @袁安峰 ?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't add this, there is an issue about this https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5918

Answer (score 19):

You can do this

```
WITH VARIABLES AS (SELECT VALUE AS VAR1, VALUE AS VAR2)
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE CROSS JOIN VARIABLES 
WHERE COLUMN = VAR1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a script variable per say; but some UIs like DataGrip (probably DBeaver as well) emulate passing variables; e.g.:

```
where date = ${start_date}
```